# How to integrate socket camera in android zxing library

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, zxing

I have created a project with zxing library and to integrate webcam in emulator, I've followed [these instructions](http://www.ecole.ensicaen.fr/~reynaud/android/webcam_in_android_emulator.html)

A java application with webcambroadcaster is working and when I run it, it starts webcam and shows video captured.

But I don't know how can I integrate socketcamera in zxing library as I'm new to Android, can anybody help for this?